# Rails: How update a model without Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have to update a **table without Model**.
Say, name of the table is "users".
If it has a Model I would update it like:

```
obj = User.find_by_email "test@example.com"
obj.name = "norman"
obj.save
```

But it just a table without any model. So, how to update this table like this?

Comment: Why not create a model for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update users set name = 'norman' where email='test@example.com'")
```